# Haversine Formula - why the absolute value?

Tags: math, haversine

I'm trying to calculate the distance from a lat, lon using haversine formula. For some reason this only works in the northern hemisphere and I'm suspecting its because of the `abs`. Once I remove the absolute value, the code works fine. So I was just wondering what is the purpose of using it?

```
'(3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((' . $latitude . ' - abs(r.latitude)) * 
pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS(' . $latitude . ' * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(r.latitude) *  
pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((' . $longitude . '-r.longitude) *  pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))) 
< ' . $radius;
```

Comment: Latitude 0 is the equador, if you have non-zero latitude, you must specify if it's north or south. I'd guess that the convention is that north latitudes are positive and south ones are negative, so, you CAN'T have and `abs` in there...

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos Thats what I was thinking too, but according to http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL (look at slide 8), you need the absolute value

Comment: There's no way to know wether you are north or south without a signed latitude because `SIN` is an odd function, that means: `SIN(-x) = -SIN(x)`